# How to join values from multiple tables based on dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

please assist with the following:
I have 2 tables PurchaseO & SalesO in database INFO.

PurchaseO:

```
ITEMNO    DATE       QTY
A         20180701   5
A         20180702   2
A         20180703   1
B         20180701   2
C         20180704   3
```

SalesO:

```
ITEMNO    DATE       QTY
A         20180701   5
A         20180704   4   
B         20180702   2
C         20180704   3
```

How can I join these two tables by DATE to get the following results:

```
ITEMNO    DATE       PurchaseQTY   SalesQTY
A         20180701   5             5
A         20180702   2
A         20180703   1
A         20180704                 4
B         20180701   2
B         20180702                 2
C         20180704   3             3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(p.itemno, s.itemno) as itemno,
       coalesce(p.date, s.date) as date,
       p.qty as purchase_qty,
       s.qty as sales_qty
from purchases p full join
     sales s
     on p.itemno = s.itemno and p.date = s.date;
```

If you have duplicate dates for a given item in either table and you want to add up the quantities, then `union all`/`group by` is a better approach:

```
select itemno, date,
       sum(purchase_qty) as purchase_qty,
       sum(sales_qty) as sales_qty
from ((select p.itemno, p.date, sum(p.qty) as purchase_qty, 0 as sales_qty
       from purchases p
       group by p.itemno, p.date
      ) union all
      (select s.itemno, s.date, 0, sum(s.qty) as sales_qty
       from purchases p
       group by p.itemno, p.date
      )
     ) sp
group by itemno, date;
```

Comment: Thank you, the full join works well. Follow up question: If the DATE fields for both the PurchaseO and SalesO sit in their own tables (say PurchaseODate and SalesODate respectively), how can I pull them into the full join query to get the same result as above? There is a unique ID (POid) that links the PurchaseO table to the PurchaseODate table. And the same for the sales tables (SOid)

Comment: @Mau . . . You should ask new questions as *questions*, not *comments*.

Answer (score 0):

You can join dates as you would join IDs

```
SELECT
  po.ITEMNO,
  so.[DATE],
  po.QTY AS [PurchaseQTY],
  so.QTY AS [SalesQTY]
FROM
  PurchasesO AS po
FULL JOIN
  SalesO AS so
ON
  so.ITEMNO = po.ITEMNO AND
  so.[DATE] = po.[DATE]
```

Comment: You need a full outer join to get all rows from both tables.

Comment: @jarlh: You are right. I missed that there are items in `SalesO` that were not included in `PurchasesO`.